# Reading a child node value from a big xml in C#

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I have a 4000 lines of xmlresponse from a service. I extracted the particular section from that big xml using required tag name

XmlNodeList xmlForms = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Form");

From this node sample partial xml looks like below

```
 <Form>
  <FormID>3434294</FormID>
  <StatusDate>0001-01-01T00:00:00</StatusDate>
  <InternalFormNo>CADFADSFSAGDSADG01</InternalFormNo>
  <ExternalFormNo>CADFASDFASFSC1001</ExternalFormNo>
  <ProposalDescription>Treatment</ProposalDescription>
  <ProposalForm>false</ProposalForm>
  <StateApprovals>
    <StateApproval>
      <StateApprovalID>2245363363636</StateApprovalID>
      <IssueLimitSet>
        <IssueLimitSetID>88</IssueLimitSetID>
        <Name>AccAdv</Name>
        <Note />
        <ModifyDate>0001-01-01T00:00:00</ModifyDate>
        <IssueLimits>
          <IssueLimit>
            <IssueLimtID>80</IssueLimtID>
            <GIAmount>62</GIAmount>
            <SIAmount>0.00</SIAmount>
            <ChangeProcessingCGIAmount>0</ChangeProcessingCGIAmount>
            <MaximumMultiSelect>0</MaximumMultiSelect>
            <CreateDate>0001-01-01T00:00:00</CreateDate>
            <ModifyDate>0001-01-01T00:00:00</ModifyDate>
          </IssueLimit>
        </IssueLimits>
      </IssueLimitSet>
      <SpecialProcessing>false</SpecialProcessing>
      <ModifyUser>TESTUSER</ModifyUser>
      <ModifyDate>2016-02-17T17:52:59.163</ModifyDate>
    </StateApproval>
  </StateApprovals>
</Form>
```

I need to read the node GIAmount and extract it's value (62). But xpath notation always giving null value to me. How to read this child node from this sub-xml. simple xpath also giving null always .

```
foreach (XmlNode form in xmlForms)
                        {
                            var statusDate= form.SelectSingleNode("/Form/StatusDate"); //This always null i am getting

}
```

----------------Original xml------------Under Variations->Forms->Form
--Some scenarios multiple form tags comes i need to read that particular node in every form-------

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Product xmlns="http://testtest.com/twmku">
  <ProductID>72</ProductID>
  <InternalDescription>AccidentAdvance</InternalDescription>
  <ExternalDescription>AccidentAdvance</ExternalDescription>
  <Variations>
    <Variation>
      <VariationID>231</VariationID>
      <InternalDescription>AccidentAdvance123</InternalDescription>
      <ExternalDescription>AccidentAdvance</ExternalDescription>
      <ProposalDescription />
      <IsProposalReady>false</IsProposalReady>      
      <StatusDate>2009-03-26T00:00:00</StatusDate>
      <EffectiveDate>2009-04-01T00:00:00</EffectiveDate>
      <WithdrawnDate>0001-01-01T00:00:00</WithdrawnDate>
      <ModifyUser>Utesruser</ModifyUser>
      <ModifyDate>2011-11-30T10:35:26.313</ModifyDate>
      <Employers />
      <Forms>
        <Form>
          <FormID>3493</FormID>        
          <IsGeneric>true</IsGeneric>
          <HasLimitsInUnits>true</HasLimitsInUnits>
          <Description>AccAdv Master Policy</Description>
          <CreateUser>US\testMW</CreateUser>
          <CreateDate>0001-01-01T00:00:00</CreateDate>
          <ModifyUser>US\testMW</ModifyUser>
          <ModifyDate>2011-12-12T11:42:40.06</ModifyDate>          
          <DataElements />
          <StateApprovals>
            <StateApproval>
              <StateApprovalID>2256556</StateApprovalID> 
              <IssueLimitSet>
                <IssueLimitSetID>88</IssueLimitSetID>
                <Name>AccAdv Modtest</Name>
                <Note />
                <ModifyDate>0001-01-01T00:00:00</ModifyDate>
                <IssueLimits>
                  <IssueLimit>
                    <IssueLimtID>80</IssueLimtID>
                    <Keyword>AccAdv Mod 1</Keyword>
                    <MinMarketingLimit>0.50</MinMarketingLimit>
                    <MaxMarketingLimit>12.00</MaxMarketingLimit>
                    <CGIAmount>0.00</CGIAmount>
                    <GIAmount>6</GIAmount>
                    <SIAmount>0.00</SIAmount>
                    <ChangeProcessingCGIAmount>0</ChangeProcessingCGIAmount>                   
                    <CreateDate>0001-01-01T00:00:00</CreateDate>
                    <ModifyDate>0001-01-01T00:00:00</ModifyDate>
                  </IssueLimit>
                </IssueLimits>
              </IssueLimitSet>
              <StateRequirementSet />
              <QuestionSet />
              <SICSet />
              <DateFiled>0001-01-01T00:00:00</DateFiled>          
              <SpecialProcessing>false</SpecialProcessing>
              <ModifyUser>JBtestD</ModifyUser>
              <ModifyDate>2016-02-18T14:39:50.927</ModifyDate>
            </StateApproval>
          </StateApprovals>
          <Parameters />
          <IsSelected>true</IsSelected>
        </Form>

        <Form>
          <FormID>3495</FormID>
          <IsGeneric>true</IsGeneric>
          <HasLimitsInUnits>true</HasLimitsInUnits>
          <Description>AccAdv Master main</Description>
          <CreateUser>US\testMqW</CreateUser>
          <CreateDate>0001-01-01T00:00:00</CreateDate>
          <ModifyUser>US\testMW</ModifyUser>
          <ModifyDate>2011-12-12T11:42:40.06</ModifyDate>
          <DataElements />
          <StateApprovals>
            <StateApproval>
              <StateApprovalID>26556</StateApprovalID>
              <IssueLimitSet>
                <IssueLimitSetID>88</IssueLimitSetID>
                <Name>AccAdv Moretest</Name>
                <Note />
                <ModifyDate>0001-01-01T00:00:00</ModifyDate>
                <IssueLimits>
                  <IssueLimit>
                    <IssueLimtID>84</IssueLimtID>
                    <Keyword>AccAdv Mod 1</Keyword>
                    <MinMarketingLimit>0.50</MinMarketingLimit>
                    <MaxMarketingLimit>12.00</MaxMarketingLimit>
                    <CGIAmount>0.00</CGIAmount>
                    <GIAmount>34</GIAmount>
                    <SIAmount>0.00</SIAmount>
                    <ChangeProcessingCGIAmount>0</ChangeProcessingCGIAmount>
                    <CreateDate>0001-01-01T00:00:00</CreateDate>
                    <ModifyDate>0001-01-01T00:00:00</ModifyDate>
                  </IssueLimit>
                </IssueLimits>
              </IssueLimitSet>
              <StateRequirementSet />
              <QuestionSet />
              <SICSet />
              <DateFiled>0001-01-01T00:00:00</DateFiled>
              <SpecialProcessing>false</SpecialProcessing>
              <ModifyUser>JBtestD</ModifyUser>
              <ModifyDate>2016-02-18T14:39:50.927</ModifyDate>
            </StateApproval>
          </StateApprovals>
          <Parameters />
          <IsSelected>true</IsSelected>
        </Form>
      </Forms>      
      <ParameterValueSets />
      <AllowCustomRates>false</AllowCustomRates>
    </Variation>
  </Variations>
</Product>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better to use *LINQ to XML*. Using its methods, it is very easy to get to any XML element.

(1) Your XML has a default namespace. It needs to be taken into account. (2) Multiple `<Form>...</Form>` elements require a loop.

> c#

```
void Main()
{
    XElement xelem = XElement.Parse(@"<Product xmlns='http://testtest.com/twmku'>
  <ProductID>72</ProductID>
  <InternalDescription>AccidentAdvance</InternalDescription>
  <ExternalDescription>AccidentAdvance</ExternalDescription>
  <Variations>
    <Variation>
      <VariationID>231</VariationID>
      <InternalDescription>AccidentAdvance123</InternalDescription>
      <ExternalDescription>AccidentAdvance</ExternalDescription>
      <ProposalDescription />
      <IsProposalReady>false</IsProposalReady>      
      <StatusDate>2009-03-26T00:00:00</StatusDate>
      <EffectiveDate>2009-04-01T00:00:00</EffectiveDate>
      <WithdrawnDate>0001-01-01T00:00:00</WithdrawnDate>
      <ModifyUser>Utesruser</ModifyUser>
      <ModifyDate>2011-11-30T10:35:26.313</ModifyDate>
      <Employers />
      <Forms>
        <Form>
          <FormID>3493</FormID>        
          <IsGeneric>true</IsGeneric>
          <HasLimitsInUnits>true</HasLimitsInUnits>
          <Description>AccAdv Master Policy</Description>
          <CreateUser>US\testMW</CreateUser>
          <CreateDate>0001-01-01T00:00:00</CreateDate>
          <ModifyUser>US\testMW</ModifyUser>
          <ModifyDate>2011-12-12T11:42:40.06</ModifyDate>          
          <DataElements />
          <StateApprovals>
            <StateApproval>
              <StateApprovalID>2256556</StateApprovalID> 
              <IssueLimitSet>
                <IssueLimitSetID>88</IssueLimitSetID>
                <Name>AccAdv Modtest</Name>
                <Note />
                <ModifyDate>0001-01-01T00:00:00</ModifyDate>
                <IssueLimits>
                  <IssueLimit>
                    <IssueLimtID>80</IssueLimtID>
                    <Keyword>AccAdv Mod 1</Keyword>
                    <MinMarketingLimit>0.50</MinMarketingLimit>
                    <MaxMarketingLimit>12.00</MaxMarketingLimit>
                    <CGIAmount>0.00</CGIAmount>
                    <GIAmount>6</GIAmount>
                    <SIAmount>0.00</SIAmount>
                    <ChangeProcessingCGIAmount>0</ChangeProcessingCGIAmount>                   
                    <CreateDate>0001-01-01T00:00:00</CreateDate>
                    <ModifyDate>0001-01-01T00:00:00</ModifyDate>
                  </IssueLimit>
                </IssueLimits>
              </IssueLimitSet>
              <StateRequirementSet />
              <QuestionSet />
              <SICSet />
              <DateFiled>0001-01-01T00:00:00</DateFiled>          
              <SpecialProcessing>false</SpecialProcessing>
              <ModifyUser>JBtestD</ModifyUser>
              <ModifyDate>2016-02-18T14:39:50.927</ModifyDate>
            </StateApproval>
          </StateApprovals>
          <Parameters />
          <IsSelected>true</IsSelected>
        </Form>
        <Form>
          <FormID>3495</FormID>
          <IsGeneric>true</IsGeneric>
          <HasLimitsInUnits>true</HasLimitsInUnits>
          <Description>AccAdv Master main</Description>
          <CreateUser>US\testMqW</CreateUser>
          <CreateDate>0001-01-01T00:00:00</CreateDate>
          <ModifyUser>US\testMW</ModifyUser>
          <ModifyDate>2011-12-12T11:42:40.06</ModifyDate>
          <DataElements />
          <StateApprovals>
            <StateApproval>
              <StateApprovalID>26556</StateApprovalID>
              <IssueLimitSet>
                <IssueLimitSetID>88</IssueLimitSetID>
                <Name>AccAdv Moretest</Name>
                <Note />
                <ModifyDate>0001-01-01T00:00:00</ModifyDate>
                <IssueLimits>
                  <IssueLimit>
                    <IssueLimtID>84</IssueLimtID>
                    <Keyword>AccAdv Mod 1</Keyword>
                    <MinMarketingLimit>0.50</MinMarketingLimit>
                    <MaxMarketingLimit>12.00</MaxMarketingLimit>
                    <CGIAmount>0.00</CGIAmount>
                    <GIAmount>34</GIAmount>
                    <SIAmount>0.00</SIAmount>
                    <ChangeProcessingCGIAmount>0</ChangeProcessingCGIAmount>
                    <CreateDate>0001-01-01T00:00:00</CreateDate>
                    <ModifyDate>0001-01-01T00:00:00</ModifyDate>
                  </IssueLimit>
                </IssueLimits>
              </IssueLimitSet>
              <StateRequirementSet />
              <QuestionSet />
              <SICSet />
              <DateFiled>0001-01-01T00:00:00</DateFiled>
              <SpecialProcessing>false</SpecialProcessing>
              <ModifyUser>JBtestD</ModifyUser>
              <ModifyDate>2016-02-18T14:39:50.927</ModifyDate>
            </StateApproval>
          </StateApprovals>
          <Parameters />
          <IsSelected>true</IsSelected>
        </Form>
      </Forms>      
      <ParameterValueSets />
      <AllowCustomRates>false</AllowCustomRates>
    </Variation>
  </Variations>
</Product>");

    //string GIAmount = GIAmount.Descendants(ns + "GIAmount").FirstOrDefault().Value;
    XNamespace ns = xelem.GetDefaultNamespace();

    foreach (var el in xelem.Descendants(ns + "GIAmount"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("GIAmount={0}", el.Value);    
    }
}
```

> Output

```
GIAmount=6
GIAmount=34
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. ur example working in an independent application. When i tried to incorporate in actual application i got exception as System.Xml.XmlException: 'Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.'
When i checked my Form variable  unecessary namespaces getting added, but in original it's not there. like <FormID xmlns="" ></FormID>  These xmlns tags getting added.

Comment: @San, please update your original post with real life XML, namespaces, etc. And I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: I have updated xml can you check now. In original response i will have only one xmlns tag which every xml document will have. Once i execute XmlNodeList xmlForms = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Form"); all form tags i am getting. If i try to write xpath expression it is not working. it always return null. to parse it to xelemt it gives the above exception

Comment: I am facing issues at parsing only. while looping through each form, form content i am trying to parse so i can extract needed value. XmlNodeList xmlForms = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Form");
foreach (XmlNode form in xmlForms)
{
XElement ele = XElement.Parse(form.ToString());

}

Comment: @San, what is missing in my answer for you? I showed how to retrieve all GIAmount values.

Comment: Thanks for ur time. Initially entire xml string kept in xmldocument and trying to parse partial xml to xelement, where i failed completely. With your inputs i have modified entire other logic using XElement. Never tried Xelement earlier. Tnx again

Comment: @San, good to hear that everything is working for you now. **LINQ to XML** is latest .Net Framework API to work with XML. Believe it or not, it is available since 2007-2008 time frame.

Answer (score 1):

You are already targeting the `Form` element, thus there's no reason to include it in the XPath. Simply skip that tag, and compose the path with its descendants.

In your case: `"StateApprovals/StateApproval/IssueLimitSet/IssueLimits/GIAmount"`

Or, more compact: `"//GIAmount"`

Note that my answer is based on the fragment of your post, and the path may change on the actual content.

Comment: I tried all the options still i get null.. When i observed my xml unecessary xmlns namespaces getting added randomly. I am not sure why xpath expressions not working for me, in one article i read like because of xmlns xpath won't work we need to remove. But if it's at one place we can remove, even tried removing with regex still giving null always.

Answer (score 0):

One value is usually not enough information.  Try xml linq like below :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml = File.ReadAllText(FILENAME);
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
            XNamespace ns = doc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();

            List<StateApproval> approvals = doc.Descendants(ns + "StateApproval").Select(x => new StateApproval()
            {
                id = (string)x.Element(ns + "StateApprovalID"),
                limitSetId = (string)x.Descendants(ns + "IssueLimitSetID").FirstOrDefault(),
                name = (string)x.Descendants(ns + "Name").FirstOrDefault(),
                modifyDate = (DateTime)x.Descendants(ns + "ModifyDate").FirstOrDefault(),
                issueLimitId = (string)x.Descendants(ns + "IssueLimtID").FirstOrDefault(),
                giAmount = (decimal)x.Descendants(ns + "GIAmount").FirstOrDefault(),
                siAmount = (decimal)x.Descendants(ns + "SIAmount").FirstOrDefault(),
                changeAmount = (decimal)x.Descendants(ns + "ChangeProcessingCGIAmount").FirstOrDefault(),
                min = (decimal)x.Descendants(ns + "MinMarketingLimit").FirstOrDefault(),
                max = (decimal)x.Descendants(ns + "MaxMarketingLimit").FirstOrDefault(),
                createDate = (DateTime)x.Descendants(ns + "CreateDate").FirstOrDefault(),
            }).ToList();
        }
    }
    public class StateApproval
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string limitSetId { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public DateTime modifyDate { get; set; }
        public string issueLimitId { get; set; }
        public decimal giAmount { get; set; }
        public decimal siAmount { get; set; }
        public decimal changeAmount { get; set; }
        public decimal min { get; set; }
        public decimal max { get; set; }
        public DateTime createDate { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Comment: I don't have uri path to provide for Load function. on runtime subset of my xml exists. it is not converting to string also. Couldn't try ur option.

Comment: Use for string : XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(string);

Comment: ya i tried. this. but for me exception giving while parsing-xmlexception Data at the root level is invalid line1 position 1. when i observed my xml getting unnecessary namespaces. For that i couldn't proceed with it. :(